# Snprintf not working in C

Tags: c, linux, printf

Can someone please help me with my error...

Heres what happen:

my program is call "open"

And heres my output:

```
user@host:~$ ./open open A
A
open
Error: Cannot creat ./././.: Is a directory
./././.user@host:~$
```

Why is the output turn out to be `././././` instead of `./A/open`?

I know the problem comes from `av[2]`.

```
printf("%s\n", av[2]);
printf("%s\n", av[1]);
snprintf(av[2], sizeof(av[2]), "./%s/%s", av[2], av[1]);
printf("%s", av[2]);
```

Comment: `sizeof(av[2])` is the size of a pointer, which is probably 4 bytes.

Comment: so I have to change it to something else? I tried delete that, but it turns out to be segmentation fault .

Comment: Why are you trying to store the result into `av[2]`? It probably doesn't have room for any extra characters beyond what it already contains.

Comment: @Barmar I think pointer size is 8 here.

Comment: I don't⋯⋯⋯ know 

Comment: You should create a buffer variable and use a pointer to it as first parameter.

Comment: I tried change the second av[2] to av[3] and it works, but I am not sure why..

Comment: Please show more code. What is `av`?. Read this:   [mcve]:

Comment: The usual name for the program's arguments is `argv[]`. Using your own name makes the question confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that `av[2]` is a pointer, so `sizeof(av[2])` is the size of a pointer, not the number of characters in the array.

The second problem is if this is the program's `argv[]` array, each element only has room for the actual argument -- you shouldn't try to store a longer string into it.

The solution is to allocate a new string that's big enough for what you want

```
size_t newlen = strlen(av[1]) + strlen(av[2]) + 4; // + 3 for ./ and /, +1 for trailing null
char *path = malloc(newlen);
if (!path) {
    printf("Unable to allocate\n");
    exit(1);
}
sprintf(path, "./%s/%s", av[2], av[1]);
printf("%s", path);
```

In this case it's not necessary to use `snprintf()`, because we calculated the size of `path` to be sufficient for the concatenation.

Comment: yes it is the argv[] array. Thank you for you explanation . Learned more stuff about C

Answer (score 4):

`snprintf(av[2], sizeof(av[2]), "./%s/%s", av[2], av[1]);` is invalid for various reasons.

1. Using `snprinf()` where source and destination overlap is UB.
2. `sizeof(av[2])` is the size of a pointer, 8 in this case, and not the size of the array.
3. Quite possible `av[2]` is of insufficient size to save the concatenation.

Comment: I get the size part now, but what's the difference between snprinf and sprintf 

Comment: @mmm `snprintf()` requires you to provide the size of the destination string, so it won't overflow.

Comment: @mmm Use of `snprintf()` is 1 of 2 steps in preventing problems with excessive _printed_ strings.  The seconds step is to use the return value of `int len = snprintf(...., size, ....)` --> `if (len < 0 || len >= size) Handle_Problem()`.  Without the second step, subsequent code may use an unexpected string.  Consider `snprintf(buf, 13, "%s", "Launch missles not");`